# Struts 2 FreeMarker Template Error stack.findValue('top') is undefined and jsp page 

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jsp, struts2

Struts 2 FreeMarker Template Error stack.findValue('top') is undefined and jsp page

```
Error on line 69, column 13 in template/simple/select.ftl
stack.findValue('top') is undefined.
It cannot be assigned to itemKey
The problematic instruction:
---- ------
==> assignment: itemKey=stack.findValue('top') [on line 69, column 13 in 
template/simple/select.ftl]
in user-directive s.iterator [on line 59, column 1 in template/simple/select.ftl]
in include "/${parameters.templateDir}/simple/select.ftl" [on line 24, column 1 in    
template/xhtml/select.ftl]
----------    
Java backtrace for programmers:
----------
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Error on line 69, column 13 in            
template/simple/select.ftl
stack.findValue('top') is undefined.
It cannot be assigned to itemKey
at freemarker.core.Assignment.accept(Assignment.java:111)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
```

basically on my JSP side I have a number of dropdowns options. 
how to solve this error ....!!!!

JSP PAGE for dropdown and so on....

```
    <html>
    <title>JSP PAGE</title>
    <body>
<s:form action="event" namespace="/" method= "post">
<h4>
        <s:textfield name="description" label="Description" size="30" />
</h4>
<h4>
        <s:textfield name="name" label="Name" />
</h4>
<h4>
    <sx:datetimepicker name="date" label="Format (DD-MM-YYYY)"              
            displayFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy" value="%{'2012-01-01'}">
    </sx:datetimepicker>
</h4>
<h4>
    <s:textfield name="type" label="Event Type" />
</h4>
<h4>
    <s:textfield name="group" label="Event Group" />
</h4>
    <s:select name="Location" headerKey="-1" label="Location" list="{cityList}">
<%-- <s:iterator value="cityList">
<option>
</option>
</s:iterator> --%>
</s:select>
    <s:submit value="Submit" method="execute" key="submit" align="center" />
</s:form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If you put the jsp page here, maybe someone can help you

Comment: @Pigueiras : Hi i have added JSP page in my question.

Comment: The `list` attribute should be just `cityList` or `%{cityList}`, if nothing else. But what version os S2 are you using? Also try using a `headerValue` since you're using a `headerKey`. What's contained in `cityList`?

Answer (score 2):

Delete any empty(`null`)values in the drop down, its referring to those values. This will resolve your problem.